# What does it mean for a person to be 'Old Testament'?

Tags: old-testament

The context of this question as follows: In the Peaky Blinders there is a scene in which Alfie Solomons, an orthodox Jew taunts Arthur Shelby for his newfound faith to which Arthur replies he is 'Old Testament' so as to intimidate him.

I was under the impression that most if not all Christians believed that the Old Testament had been superseded by the New Testament, so what is meant by Arthur's statement?

In the show his wife - Linda Shelby - is said to be a Quaker, is this a belief common to the Quakers or does Arthur follow a different denomination to his wife?

Comment: This dialogue does not convey the expressions used by Christians in self-identifying Christian groups. It is merely the writing of an individual author and their own, personal viewpoint of other people's religion. I suggest this is off-topic as it is based on opinion and is not a factual apprehension of real Christianity.

Comment: Since context can make a world of difference, it would make it a lot easier for people to answer this if the question indicated *which* episode and at *what time* the dialog occurred, so they can hear it for themselves.  (It's not good to expect answerers to search for information that should have been included in the question.)

Comment: In "*Arthur replies he is …*", does "he" refer to Arthur or Alfie?  The answers might be different depending upon which one it is.

Comment: The television series "Peaky Blinders" was recently shown on British TV.  It's about thugs and gangsters in the West Midlands of England who do dreadful things to their enemies (they have razor blades in the peaks of their caps). It's all FICTION and the dialogue has been made up by a scriptwriter. The series is not about Christianity.  No wonder you are confused.  Ray Butterworth's answer is useful.

Comment: @RayButterworth 'he' refers to Arthur in this case

Answer (score 2):

Many people confuse Old/New Testament with Old/New Covenant.  The Testaments usually refer to the books, and the Covenants to the deals made in those books between God and physical/spiritual Israel.

Almost all Christians believe they are part of a New Covenant with God to set an example of personal behaviour, and not part of the Old Covenant, which was intended for the physical nation of Israel to set a societal example to the world.

Some, but by no means all or even most, Christian denominations also hold the belief that the Old Testament book is no longer relevant or applicable to them.

As for Quakers (Friends), they don't consider either part of the Bible nearly as seriously as most other denominations.  They view it not as a source of literal truth, but as a source of spiritual principles and ideas.

> God hath seen that herein we should see as in a looking-glass the conditions and experiences of the saints of old, that finding our experiences to answer to theirs, we might be time more confirmed and comforted and our hope of obtaining the same end strengthened.... This is the great work of the Scriptures and their service to us, that we may witness them fulfilled in us, and so discern the stamp of God’s Spirit and ways upon them by the inward acquaintance we have with the same Spirit and work in our hearts.
> — Robert Barclay, quoted in [A Quaker Approach to the Bible - by Henry Joel Cadbury](https://universalistfriends.org/cadbury-1.html)

Comment: So the implication then is that he is of a Christian denomination that believes the Old Testament is still applicable? What are some prominent denominations who hold this belief?